# Limit file viewing based on user count

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-access

**Background**
Due to licencing on our Medical PDF Documents, our Doctors are restricted to only have 2-3 of them viewing a PDF document at once.
While we know we could just make a copy of everything and distribute it among everyone, our Doctors feel that they don't want to breach the licence, thus need an effective way to restrict access.

**Challenge**
While I understand the basic concept of this, I had the idea to use one of two ways:

1. Have folder access rights on the on the physical PC, to hard-limit the amount of users entering.
2. Store the information in a database, making the web application restrict the users.

**Conclusion**
I *really* don't want to use hard file access rights. This isn't nearly diverse enough for my liking.
I would rather have the application restrict access, because it will then be easier for me to set rights based on users.

**My Question**
If I did have it database side, I will go about storing the physical PDF's in a folder, then linking them to a page. This page will have a button to open the PDF, that will be enabled/disabled based on the current amount of people who have clicked on it.
When a person clicks 'Close' on the PDF, the application will -1 to the count, allowing a person to access the PDF.

How would I make my application know the PDF has closed?

Comment: is the pdf diplayed on the iframe or full page?

Comment: I was hoping the PDF will be displayed in a new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should display the pdf in an iframe and provide a "Close" button outside that iframe. This way you will be able to track your open documents' count and act accordingly.

Comment: I have never used an iFrame before. Could you give a demo on how I'd implement it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames

Comment: what if the user closes the tab instead of clicking the "Close" button. this will not work too.

Comment: then you update the active count inside user's sesion_end() event. This will get generated when user has closed the window after the specified session timeout value